# Efficient way of programming in Python

Tags: python, performance, coding-style

It may seem like an offtopic question, but I'm wondering about the right way (or better to say efficient way) to programme.

Let's say we have a web application and inside a function we have to check that a dictionary key has a certain value (or it can be applied to any object attribute check). Which of these ways are more efficient (in memory or speed) and why? Or if this is a wrong way to do that, why?

```
if myDictionary.get("xy") == "defined value":
    runSomeFunction(myDictionary.get("xy"))
```

or

```
myVar = myDictonary.get("xy", "")
if myVar == "defined value":
    runSomeFunction(myVar)
```

There may be a more diverse discussion in the ways we approach this code - in the web application (with hundreds of requests per minute) or in a normal script as a optimal way of programming.

Thanks in advance for any opinion.

Comment: Depends on how expensive .get("xy") is and what you want to optimize for: cpu, memory i/o...

Comment: In terms of memory it is pretty much the same - the referenced object is only once in memory in both cases. The only difference is the memory used by the temporary variable, and that's insignificant.

Comment: @ThiefMaster thanks, I was wondering if there is some memory "overhead" if I can call it like that for creating a temp variable than for functional call.

Comment: The variable needs some memory of course, but it's just a "label" for the object it "contains". So the actual object is not copied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this kind of micro-optimization is relevant, using a scripting language is the wrong choice of technology. So the only proper answer besides the common "benchmark it" is: It does not really matter. Keep the code readable.

More technical explanation: `dict` is implemented using a hash map, i.e. it has `O(1)` lookup. So accessing an element is very fast. My guess would be that the temporary variable is a little bit faster since it does not involve calculating the hash of the key twice.

A `timeit` benchmark with 1 million iterations shows the following times:

- 0.3209540843963623 (no temp var)
- 0.3401560783386230 (temp var)

So using the temporary variable is actually a little bit slower. But note that this was for 1M iterations. So the actual average difference each time was just 0.00000002 seconds. That's nothing and just proves my initial point: Don't micro-optimize things that do not need to be optimized. Keep your code readable instead.

Comment: Well, if it's O(1) than it actually doesn't matter :)
And what if we have a object getter and will get any attribute of the object (let's cut it just to simple types like integers, strings, ...)

Comment: @ThiefMaster While it's true that dictionary lookups are very fast, `get()` (as used in the OP's code) is a function call, and they are generally *not* fast in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you use the `get()` method of the dict. This method should be used in cases where you don't know if a key exists – you didn't mention that to be the case. So I'm wondering why you don't just do:

```
if myDictionary["xy"] == "defined value":
    ...
```

A note to style: Typically CamelCasing is only used for class names; more Pythonic names would be `my_dictionary` and `run_some_function`.

A dictionary look-up is fast. Be sure that this is indeed a bottleneck by benchmarking your application – without knowing your code, I'm almost certain it is not. Python internally uses dictionaries for almost everything, it is unlikely that this particular dictionary access causes you performance problems.

Comment: Just because it is called a dict does not mean it is a dict. Quack :)